# Trying to read csv file into ArrayList in Java but elements are unintentionally merging?

Tags: java, csv, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have a csv file that contains values that im trying to put into an arraylist but the last value of a line merges with the first value of the second line.
See:

I have data like this,

```
Account Number,Investment Account,Bank Number,Gender,Balance
2544434, Y, 145556, F,1000
2544578, N, 254309, M, 20000
2544230, N, 150365, F, 500000
```

and my code so far is this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here 
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("data.csv"));
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            sc.nextLine();

            while(sc.hasNext()) {
               list.add(sc.next());
            }
            System.out.println(list.get(4))

}
```

The output looks like this,

```
1000
2544578
```

with both the last and first value of their respective rows merging into one when i'd like to keep it separate. I've searched for similar questions and could not find any so i wonder if anyone here can possible help. **I'd like this to be done using Scanner module.**

Comment: Because of your delimeter. Read up to "\n" instead, that'll give you each line. Then you can break that line up by using ","

Comment: Or alternatively, iterate with `while(sc.hasNextLine())`

Comment: When changing it to .hasNextLine() it still gives the same output, how would i need to implement you first solution to see if that will work? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you have already pointed out that a new line does not separate each element of the CSV format.
To fix this you can use the overloaded method of `useDelimiter` to supply a pattern, wherein the delimiter is **either** a comma followed by a space or a new line.

Some regex like so:

> ,\W|[\n]

Comment: If you don't want to use regex (very reasonable), you should use Ceelos' suggestion which is a comment on the question

Comment: so sc.useDelimiter(",\\W|[\\n]") would be an adequate replacement like you suggested or as Ceelos' mentioned to read to the "\n" .nextLine() would be sufficient. Seems simple, thanks for your help

Comment: Yep, pretty close, it accepts a `String` or a `Pattern` (which would be a regular expression), I believe you'd have to do `sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(",\\W|[\\n]"))`.

Comment: Thanks again, i will probably make a java class object and then read the csv file into that so i don't need to rely on using pattern compile. I probably should or started with that but thank you for giving me clarity on the problem!